# How to change placeHolder of search textbox in the multiselect?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, placeholder

How to change placeHolder of search textbox in the multiselect?

I mean the textarea that allows you to search for an item by name.(attached image)
The one below the selected elements.
[image]

The input with ' .k-input.k-valid" ' css class. This input show.

This input is only shown at the multiselect onchange

```
 <div id="example" >
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>Products</h4>
        <select id="products"></select>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
                placeholder: "Select products...",
                dataTextField: "ProductName",
                dataValueField: "ProductID",
                autoBind: false,
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                        }
                    }
                },
                value: [
                    { ProductName: "Chang", ProductID: 2 },
                    { ProductName: "Uncle Bob's Organic Dried Pears", ProductID: 7 }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, show us your code..

Comment: Also, maybe you will find it in the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-placeholder)

Comment: it is not that placeholder.
I have already visited the documentation

Comment: the code is not needed.
it is a common multiselect of kendo with serverFiltering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would do this

After the component declaration add this to modify the constructed input element that is part of the mult-select component.

```
var input = $("#products").data("kendoMultiSelect").input;
input.prop("placeholder", "need more product");
```

There are some issues with width of input clipping the placeholder, so you might need to add css to widen or overflow (if that is possible with a placeholder value).

An alternative would be to add a tool tip for the multi-select.